Django render a view depending geolocation from the browser
I'm trying to load my home page according to the geolocation given by the browser, if the coordinates are ok, I load a list of airports around these coordinates, otherwise I load all airports.
However, I can't manage this between GET & POST requests. Each time I get all the airports in the page.
In fact when the view is loaded (by the GET request) all airport are displayed, after when the page is entirely loaded the POST event is raised with the GPS information. So the list of airports around location is performed but the rendering is always wrong.
Many thanks for your help
urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home_view),

views.py
def home_view(request):   

        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') 

        if request.method == 'POST':
             Latitude = float(request.POST.get('latitude'))
             Longitude = float(request.POST.get('longitude'))
             context = aviationweatherapi.getStationInfo(Latitude,Longitude)
             print ("Get airports list around current GPS location")
             
        else:
            #The request is GET
            context = aviationweatherapi.getStationInfo(None, None)
            print ("Get all airports")
        
        context.update({'IP':ip})
        
        return render(request,'acceuil.html',context)


template_Base.html (base of the acceuil.html)
<body>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% block contenu %} {% endblock %}

    

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        const findLoc = () => {
             const success = (position) => {
                const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                const longitude = position.coords.longitude; 
                var data = {'latitude': latitude,
                            'longitude': longitude };
                data.csrfmiddlewaretoken = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
                console.log('Location is on');
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("LocationLat").innerHTML = latitude;
                document.getElementById("LocationLon").innerHTML = longitude;
                $.post("/", data);
            }
    
            const error = () => {
                console.log('Location gathering Not allowed')
                const latitude = 0  // Default Latitude
                const longitude = 0    // Default Longtitude
                var data = {'latitude': latitude,
                            'longitude': longitude,
                        };
                data.csrfmiddlewaretoken = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("LocationLat").innerHTML = "err.latitude";
                document.getElementById("LocationLon").innerHTML = "err.longitude";
                $.post("/", data);
            }
    
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error);
        }
        // Location is fetched when user loads screen
        Window.onload = findLoc();
      </script>



Without seeing navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error); it is hard to see what exactly is going on. But one thing seems weird. After your get request the post is automatically called, but then on reloading it will be called again and again by window.onload, because your base.html is reloaded and the script is called again.

thanks, yes you 're right, that's why i change my strategy, the post request is performed by ajax, and inside the javascript when i receive the answer, i build the html
